# How to put a polymer app into a fixed/max width container

Tags: layout, polymer

Is there a way to put your whole polymer app (including the drawer of an app-drawer-layout) into a fixed or max width container?

Usually in web design, if we have an app that does not look good when exceeding a certain width, we put it into some

```
margin: auto;
width: 1200px;
```

top-level container. I cannot figure out how to do this with polymer, because the drawer panel used some fixed, absolute positioning. All (official) examples only constrain the width of the app content and not the whole app with all its drawers, headers, etc.

Look here for a bad example: http://cds-polymer.appspot.com/contacts/all

In my opinion this look really bad with page header and drawer detached from the content and a lot of negative space between them. So how can we design this properly with polymer?

Comment: Putting a min or max width in an application isn't a good practice.
You can make the side navigation bar stay open so it can reduce the content area when the view width is too large, also you can think about making some card-based layout to use more space, it could be a list of cards or a mosaic of cards.

Answer (score 1):

I found this polymer element that does what you need: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-fit-behavior?active=Polymer.IronFitBehavior hope it helps

Comment: When answering with a link it's important to state what about the page is useful in your answer, including the most pertinent part(s) and the link giving credit to the site. That way, if the link rots and breaks, at least there'll be enough information to help. Right now, if the link breaks your answer will make no sense.

Comment: Actually this is more useful if you want to align some divs on top of other elements. It does not help me, since the drawer is positioned absolutely regardless.